# Php Curl to Json

Tags: php, json, curl

I can get data from a website with CURL.
I want to convert this data to json.

my code:

```
<?php
function Curlconnect($start,$end,$website) {
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $website);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    $website = curl_exec($ch);
    preg_match_all('@'.$start.'(.*?)'.$end.'@si',$website,$ver);
    return $ver[1];
    curl_close($ch);
}

function nt($start,$bit,$data,$a) {
    preg_match_all('@'.$start.'(.*?)'.$bit.'@si',$data,$ver);
    return $ver[1];
}

$url = 'http://www.url.com';
$getdata = Curlconnect('<h4','h4>',$url);
for ($a=0; $a<count($getdata); $a++) {
    $printdata = nt('>','</',$getdata[$a],$a);
    echo $printdata[0]. '<br />';
}
?>
```

Output:

```
1
27
32
66
94
```

I want to convert this data to json like that:

```
{
        "data":{
            "numbers":
                [
                       "1",
                       "27",
                       "32",
                       "66",
                       "94",
                ]
        }
}
```

How Can I do that?

Thank you very much.

Comment: $numbersData = []; on foreach $numbersData[] = $getdata[$a];

Comment: finally: echo json_encode(['data' => ['numbers' => $numbersData ] ]);

Comment: Hi @SebastiaoMarcos Thank you very much.

Comment: please vote comment!

Comment: done @SebastiaoMarcos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this

```
$url = 'http://www.url.com';
$getdata  = Curlconnect('<h4','h4>',$url);
$jsonData = ["data"];
$jsonData["numbers"] = [];
for ($a=0; $a<count($getdata); $a++) {
    $printdata = nt('>','</',$getdata[$a],$a);
    $jsonData["numbers"][] = $printdata[0];
}

echo json_encode($jsonData);
```

Comment: Hi @DollyAswin
Thank you very much, this is perfect.